# Connect Bluetooth keyboard to Mac from log in

Tags: keyboard, wifi

Somehow, my wireless keyboard disconnected from my computer. Now, when I try to log in, I can’t because my keyboard isn’t connected. I replaced batteries, held down button and restarted my computer without any luck. Any idea how to reconnect my keyboard to my desktop Mac even though I am logged out? Thanks!!

Comment: connect a non-wireless keyboard and check under System-Preferences for the right wireless keyboard config. Or try going into Safe Mode (it should work to allow you to press SHIFT on boot time once the Apple Logo show, keep SHIFT presed) It may be a configuration that is turning it off during normal boot. You can fix under System Preferences.